# Undefined Index Behavior

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array in PHP that is currently null, shouldn't accessing an undefined index present an E_NOTICE level error?

If I have the following snippet of code:

```
$myArray = null;
echo $myArray['foo']['bar'];
```

I would expect an error but it runs without issue.  I've verified my log level to be set to E_ALL. Is there something I'm missing or is PHP happy returning null for undefined indexes as long as you aren't trying to modify the data?

Comment: try to visit bugs.php.net As for me, it's strange behaviour. $myArray=array(); echo $myArray['foo']['bar']; gets error as I think

Comment: @RiaD:No error found. http://www.meandeviation.com/tutorials/learnphp/php-syntax-check/v4/do-syntax-check.php

Comment: @karthik my code provides E_NOTICE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the undefined index only triggers for not null variables (don't ask me why). This will trigger a notice though:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $myArray = array();
    echo $myArray['foo']['bar'];
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

no, it doesn't show any error when $myArray is set to null.
if it is an empty array or any other value except for null then it returns a E_NOTICE level error.
i actualy don't know why but it is as it is.

Comment: Just tested and you're right.  Setting to null gives no error, but an empty array does.